# Auto Login After successful registration in laravel 6 getting an error

Tags: laravel

I am getting an error while trying to Auto Login After successful registration in laravel 6 getting the following error.

> Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in

My Registercontroller is

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{

use RegistersUsers;

protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

public function __construct()
{
     $this->middleware('guest');
   // $this->middleware(['auth','verified']);
}

protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
     'name' => ['required', 'min:3'],
        'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $username = slugify($data['name'])."-".mt_rand(10000, 99999);
    $user =  User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $username,
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'email_token' => base64_encode($data['email']),

    ]);

    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);

}

}
```

User Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
 use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
 use App\Jobs\SendEmailJob;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
use Notifiable;

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [


   'email','name','password','username','picture',
   'ip_address','email_verified_at','email_token','verified'
];




/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];


function socialProviders(){

    return $this->hasMany(socialProvider::class);
}


  // This is the code define in the sendEmailVerificationNotification
  public function sendEmailVerificationNotification()
   {
     SendEmailJob::dispatch($this);
   }
 }
```

Comment: does your user model implements `Authenticatable` interface??

Comment: Updated User Model please check

Comment: `implements MustVerifyEmail` remove this from user model and try again.

Comment: same error!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have overwritten the registration logic, but you have ignored the fact that `create` method needs to return an instance of `App\User` - or at least a class that implements `Authenticatable`.

Take a look at the [original logic](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php#L59-L72); you will see that the docblock shows that an instance of `App\User` is being returned and that the original implementation returns the result of the `User::create()` call.

To get your custom method working, update it like so:

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => slugify($data['name'])."-".mt_rand(10000, 99999);,
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'email_token' => base64_encode($data['email']),

    ]);
}
```

Laravel will take care of logging the user in [by default](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php#L35) anyway.